# how do I add support for windowed mode [Or, small windowed mode, free form window, floating window, etc. ]?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, multitasking

## Details:

I have been searching for this for a while. I want my android app to also have this support. I got answers such as `android:resizeableActivity="true"` didn't do much. I can't find a clear documentation or tutorial or even samples for achieving this. I want the entire app to support floating windowed mode such as shown in the screenshot given below.

#### I want to be clear, I AM NOT LOOKING FOR POP-UP WINDOW SUPPORT SUCH AS ONES PROVIDED BY YOUTUBE OF BROWSERS.

## Example of what I am looking for:

A sample of windowed mode I am looking for. (here, chrome is in windowed mode)

[image: floating app screenshot]

This image shows the button used to enter windowed mode. (i.e. `Small window` button)

[image: button sample]

Comment: Unclear if you've seen: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/multi-window-support and possibly https://developer.android.com/topic/arc/window-management